# What is it called when you use "I would do X" to show strength of feeling?

Tags: terminology

For instance, in The Proclaimers' hit song *I'm Gonna Be* they say

> I would walk five hundred miles, and
>   
> I would walk five hundred more
>   
> Just to be the man who walked a thousand miles to fall down at your door

The protagonist in the song isn't literally going to walk a thousand miles, they're using this construction to intensify their description of their feeling for the person they're singing to/about.

If I were describing it in a phrase I might say "exaggeration for effect," but is there a (more) specific term for it? If so, what is it?

Comment: It is an ***hyperbole.*** https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hyperbole

Comment: @Hachi - That's definitely true, thanks, and would make a good answer. I have this sense that there's another word or term that I can't quite remember that fits even better, but *hyperbole* certainly also fits.

Comment: *Embroidery*? *Embellishment*?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - Both good. The more I think about it, the more convinced I am that *hyperbole* **is** the word I was thinking of.